# Retrieving $_SESSION values After PHP Redirect

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-state

This should be an easy PHP mySQL question (I'm assuming it's sort of PHP and mySQL 101 but I'm having trouble finding an answer)...

I have a registration form I've created and when the form is filled out and submitted it posts to a register_user.php page. The code on that page is this:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("my_host","my_username","my_password");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

// username and password sent from form
//NEVER Remove the mysql_real_escape_string. Else there could be an Sql-Injection!
$firstname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$sql="INSERT INTO my_table (firstName, lastName, email, password)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[email]', '$_POST[password]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  session_start();
  // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "profile.php"
  $_SESSION['firstname']='$_POST[firstname]';
  $_SESSION['lastname']='$_POST[lastname]';
  $_SESSION['email']='$_POST[email]';
  $_SESSION['password']='$_POST[password]';
  header("location:profile.php");
?>
```

As you can see, it redirects to a page called profile.php . On profile.php I'm trying to echo out the session variables by saying:

```
<?php echo "Hello". $_SESSION['firstname']; ?>
```

I'm assuming the variable loses it's value upon the redirect from register_user.php to profile.php (at least this is what I gather from my research thus far). I'm thinking I have to use `session_start();` on the profile.php to declare the variables again but I don't know how to set the variables to the appropriate values. In register_user.php I was able to use the post values from the form on the previous page but by the time it redirects to profile.php I can no longer do that.

Can someone please explain how I can retrieve those values on profile.php? (again I have a feeling this is a very basic question but I'm still learning so be gentle haha :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quote around `$_POST` and hence your values are not applied to `$_SESSION` and you were missing quotes inside

```
$_POST['value']
-------^-----^

$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
```

And always declare `session_start();` on the top of the page and ofcourse you need to declare `session_start();` on the other page before you echo out the session value

Moreover use `mysqli_()` instead of `mysql_()`

Comment: That's perfect (I can accept your answer in five minutes...).

Comment: Also, can mysqli_() be used universally instead of mysql_() . I'm going to read up on it now. I'm just learning mySQL

Comment: @MxmastaMills and yea sanitize your data using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` atleast, happy coding :)

Comment: @MxmastaMills yes if you are surely going to use MySQL as a database always than you should use `mysqli_()` as community will deprecate `mysql_()` soon, if you think you'll switch the database later use `PDO`

Comment: I'm just testing it out now and I get this error (or one similar) every time I change mysql_() to mysqli_() : `Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/content/blablabla/profile.php on line 8` . I know that can be an error if the syntax isn't right (or there's a problem with what's happening) but I literally just did a replace all of "mysql_" to "mysqli_" in TextWrangler and that happened. Any ideas why?

Comment: No you simply cannot replace `mysql_()` to `mysqli_()` they have difference in function parameters, read the php documentation

Comment: I suppose I was I trying to cheat a little for a quick fix! Thanks for all the help, you've got me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: haha no you cannot do it like that, go slow, study perfectly, all the best and you welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the escaped data at all, lol. Try using PDO (or mysqli <-- i is at the end) with prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the session_start() command from your registration form on the top of the page cause my feeling (I'm a beginner myself so bear with me) is that it's not actually taking any of the registration process into account.

I've always been told that the session start command itself should always happen at the beginning of the page, so before you even start the registration form code. Then on the next page you are redirecting to you should also start with session_start at the top of the page.